# Comparar atributos de div diferentes de um mesmo arquivo html

Tags: javascript, html

a minha dúvida é: tenho uma div com um checkbox e uma outra com imagem, gostaria que depois que o usuario marcasse a div com checkbox e clicasse em um botao de confirmação, a minha função em js checasse se o checkbox está marcado e se estiver ele compara de o atributo 'id' do checkbox é igual ao 'value' da imagem e se for ele esconde o checkbox e mostra a imagem.

O html é:

```
<div class="toggle div-inline" style="display: "> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="consultar_acervo"  name="toggle"> <span>Consultar Acervos</span> 
    <label for="consultar_acervo"></label>
  </div>

    <div class="column zoom" style="display:none">
    <a href="https://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=biblioteca&action=main:pesquisasimples" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Consultar Acervo" target=“_blank”>
      <img src="../images/img_nature.jpg" alt="Fjords" style="width:100%" value="consultar-acervo" id1= "icons">
    </a>
```

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="aplica" onclick="checar()"> Aplicar</button>
```

no javascript eu já consegui fazer a função que verifica se o checkbox está marcado, sei que essa comparação de atributos é feita dentro do if mas não sei como fazê-la, vcs podem me ajudar?

O arquivo Js

```
function checar(){

var checa = document.getElementsByName("toggle");

for (var i=0;i<checa.length;i++){ 
    if (checa[i].checked == true){ 
        // CheckBox Marcado... Faça alguma coisa...

    }  else {
       // CheckBox Não Marcado... Faça alguma outra coisa...
    }
}

}
```

Comment: IDs são únicos - Cada página pode ter apenas um elemento com aquele ID.

Comment: Olá Leo Caracciolo, obrigada pela ajuda. Eu me expressei mal, na vdd quero comparar o' id' do checkbox com o 'value' da imagem, esses dois podem ter valores iguai ou tbm não?

Comment: Imagem não tem value

Comment: Se eu usar 'name', é válido?

Comment: Como irá marcar se está tudo escondido com display: none?

Comment: Pode ser com jquery?

Comment: Foi erro meu dvd, o check inicia só com " display= ". Pode sim Leo Caracciolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - Com javascript puro utilizando atributo [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)**

Qualquer atributo de qualquer elemento no qual o nome do atributo inicia com `data-` é um atributo data, que pode ser lido através da propriedade `dataset`.

**exemplo:**

```
<elemento id="qqid" data-id="valorId"> 
var qqvar = document.getElementById('qqid');
var valor = qqvar.dataset.id; //valorId
```

> O nome do atributo data precisa ser precedido do termo "data-" e precisa de pelo menos um caractere após o hífen dentro dos padrões de nome no HTML.

**Aplicando ao seu script**

```js
function checar(){

    if(document.getElementById("check").checked == true){
        alert("CheckBox Marcado... Faça alguma coisa...");
                    
          var atributoIdCheckbox = document.getElementById('check');
          var dataCheckbox = atributoIdCheckbox.dataset.id;
          console.log(dataCheckbox);

          var atributoIdCheckbox = document.getElementById('icons');
          var dataImage = atributoIdCheckbox.dataset.id;
          console.log(dataImage);
                    
            if (dataCheckbox==dataImage){
               document.getElementById("zoom").style.display = 'block';
               document.getElementById("consulta").style.display = 'none';
               document.getElementById("aplica").style.display = 'none';
            }else{
                 alert("diferentes");
            }

     }  else {
        alert("CheckBox Não Marcado... Faça alguma outra coisa...");

     }

}
```

```html
<div id="consulta" class="toggle div-inline"> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" data-id="consultar-acervo" name="toggle"> <span>Consultar Acervos</span> 
    <label for="consultar_acervo"></label>
</div>

<div id="zoom" class="column zoom" style="display: none;">
     <a href="https://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=biblioteca&action=main:pesquisasimples" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Consultar Acervo" target=“_blank”>
     <input type="hidden" value="consultar-acervo"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEYos.png" alt="Fjords" style="width:200px" data-id="consultar-acervo" id="icons">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="aplica" onclick="checar()"> Aplicar</button>
 </div>
```

**2 - Com Jquery**

```js
function checar(){

    if(document.getElementById("check").checked == true){
        alert("CheckBox Marcado... Faça alguma coisa...");
                
        $idCheckbox = $('#check').attr('data-id');
        console.log($idCheckbox);

        $idImage = ($("#icons").data("sample-id"));
        console.log($idImage);
                
        if ($idCheckbox==$idImage){
          $(".zoom").show();
          $(".div-inline").hide();
          $("#aplica").hide();
        }else{
          alert("diferentes");
        }

    }  else {
       alert("CheckBox Não Marcado... Faça alguma outra coisa...");

    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle div-inline"> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="check" data-id="consultar-acervo" name="toggle"> <span>Consultar Acervos</span> 
     <label for="consultar_acervo"></label>
</div>

<div class="column zoom" style="display:none">
     <a href="https://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=biblioteca&action=main:pesquisasimples" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Consultar Acervo" target=“_blank”>
     <input type="hidden" value="consultar-acervo"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEYos.png" alt="Fjords" style="width:200px" data-sample-id="consultar-acervo" id="icons">
      </a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="aplica" onclick="checar()"> Aplicar</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada Leo Caracciolo!! Era isso mesmo que eu procurava!